# Why I'm getting a RecursionError only if I call the recursive function twice on the same line?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm working with recursive functions in Python. I use memoization to speed up the computation.

The following snippet fails with a `RecursionError` ("maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison") if `n` >= 333 (YMMV):

```
from scipy.special import binom
from sys import argv

def memoized(func):
    cache = {}
    def new_func(*args):
        if args in cache:
             return cache[args]
        else:
             temp = cache[args] = func(*args)
             return temp
    return new_func

def p(N, n, k):
    return binom(n, k) * (1 / N)**k * (1 - 1/N)**(n-k)

@memoized
def X(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1

    s = 0
    for k in range(1,n):
        s += p(2, n, k) * (X(k)+X(n-k))

    return (1 + (1/2)**(n-1) * X(0) + s) / (1 - (1/2)**(n-1))

n = int(argv[1])
print('efficiency: ' + str(X(n) / n))
```

However, If I split the `for` loop in two different sums, it works as expected with bigger values of `n`:

```
from scipy.special import binom
from sys import argv

def memoized(func):
    cache = {}
    def new_func(*args):
        if args in cache:
             return cache[args]
        else:
             temp = cache[args] = func(*args)
             return temp
    return new_func

def p(N, n, k):
    return binom(n, k) * (1 / N)**k * (1 - 1/N)**(n-k)

@memoized
def X(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1

    s1 = 0
    for k in range(1,n):
        s1 += p(2, n, k) * X(k)

    s2 = 0
    for k in range(1,n):
        s2 += p(2, n, k) * X(n-k)

    return (1 + (1/2)**(n-1) * X(0) + s1+s2) / (1 - (1/2)**(n-1))

n = int(argv[1])
print('efficiency: ' + str(X(n) / n))
```

Why is that? Why calling twice the `X()` function on the same line affects whether it exceeds the recursion depth?

Comment: Try logging the values of n that are being invoked, or tracing it by hand with pencil and paper.

Comment: @JoshLee the first snippet uses `n-1` until it reaches 1, the second snippet the other way round (1 up to `n`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your second (working) example:

```
for k in range(1,n):
    s1 += p(2, n, k) * X(k)
```

The first thing you do is execute `X()` with values starting at 1 and counting up to `k`. Each time it iterates through this loop, it's going to recurse into `X()` at most once, since all the previous values are memoized already. So no problem with recursion limits. Then you get here:

```
for k in range(1,n):
    s2 += p(2, n, k) * X(n-k)
```

This is just counting down the same values of `n` as you used previously (in the opposite order), so all calls to `X()` are already memoized. No problem. In fact, with the memoization, this version is hardly recursing at all.

Now look at your first example:

```
for k in range(1,n):
    s += p(2, n, k) * (X(k)+X(n-k))
```

The first time through the loop, `k` is 1. You'll call `X(1)`, which is fine, but then you go right to `X(n-1)`. Since you haven't memoized anything other than `X(1)` yet, that's going to start a chain of recursion that's going to count all the way back to 1. This will definitely be susceptible to hitting recursion limits.